# container-fluid and row wrap are creating a web page larger than 100vh because of column padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a section of my site which when I exclude in php gives me a normal no horizontal scrolling site. But If I include this section it adds 20px worth of horizontal scrolling on the site.

```
<section id="options">
<div style="padding: 100px 0; background-color: white;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-24">
```

So that is the start of the section, I use a 24 column compiled version of bootstrap and most of the columns get a 10px right and left padding. But shouldn't the containers and rows prevent this from making the website extend beyond it's 100% width? I do not want to have to add a no-side-padding class to every damn 24 width column I make.....?

You can see the site here http://120.147.163.197/myleisure.com.au/

So container-fluid gets 10px padding:

```
.container-fluid {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

why does row get -10px margin?

```
.row {
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: -10px;
}
```

And all columns have 10px padding.

Where is this problem arising from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this happens when you nest rows within rows. Noted.